# pyspark collect_list but limit to max N results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following pyspark logic intended to group on some target columns and then collect another target column into an array:

```
(
    df
    .groupBy(groupby_cols)
    .agg(
        F.collect_list(
            F.col(target_col)
        ).alias(target_col)
    )
)
```

I would like to limit the results to keep at most `N` values for each collected list such that the resulting target column is composed of cells with arrays of at most length `N`.

Right now, I can achieve this in pyspark with a UDF that takes the `target_col` and applies a lambda: `lambda x: x[:N]` on each cell, but this seems to be an inefficient means to achieving the behavior I seek.

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

(
    df
    .withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(
        Window.partitionBy(groupby_cols).orderBy(orderby_cols) # orderby_cols can be replaced by F.rand(1) if you don't mind which will be stayed/dropped
        )) # this will count from 1, for every element in the groupby_cols
    .filter(f"rn <= {N}") # removes all instances that larger than N
    .groupBy(groupby_cols)
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.col(target_col)).alias(target_col))
)
```

This should do the trick